# Finding a Liapunov function. Is my analysis correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following system of differential equations $x'=f(x)$:
\begin{equation}
x_1' = -x_1 -x_2^3 \\
x_2' = x_1-x_2
\end{equation}

Here is the Liapunov function I wish to use: $V(x_1, x_2) = \alpha x_1^2 + \beta x_2^4$. So I need to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that satisfy the following 3 Liapunov conditions:

The conditions to be a Liapunov funtion w.r.t the origin $x_0$:

1) $V(0, 0) = 0$

Condition 1) is clearly true.

2) $V(x) > 0$ for all $x\neq x_0$ This is clearly true for $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\beta \geq 0$ but not both equal to $0$.

3) $\nabla V\cdot f \leq 0$ for all $x$:

\begin{align}
\nabla V\cdot f &= 2\alpha x_1(-x_1-x_2^3) + 4\beta x_2 (x_1-x_2)\\
                &= -2\alpha x_1^2 -2\alpha x_1x_2^3 + 4\beta x_1x_2 - 4\beta x_2^2\\
                &= -4\beta x_2^2 -2\alpha x_1^2 -2\alpha x_1x_2^3 +4\beta x_1x_2\\
                &= -4\beta x_2^2 -2\alpha + x_1x_2(-2\alpha x_2^2+4\beta)
\end{align}

In order for condition 3) to hold, that is $\nabla V(x)\cdot f \leq 0$ for all $x$, then the third term must equal $0$. That is we need:
\begin{equation}
-2\alpha x_2^2+4\beta =0
\end{equation}
If this is the case, all solutions depend on $x_2$ unless both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equal $0$ which cannot happen as condition 2) would not be satisfied.

This is where I am stuck. Please help!

Comment: What is this $f$ you are throwing in the pot?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Are you choosing that function or the problem is dictating it's use? That is not the best choice! Regards

Comment: The problem requires that... and the system is $x'=f(x)$

Comment: I originally copied the system down wrong (just fixed it) but I copied the correct analysis from my paper. And yes I have the write $V$

Comment: $x_2 - x_2 = 0$ :-)

Comment: Hahah Thanks. What do you think now?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Does the answer below make sense? Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are given

$$x_1' = -x_1 -x_2^3 \\
x_2' = x_1-x_2$$

with

$$V(x_1, x_2) = \alpha x_1^2 + \beta x_2^4$$

We have:

\begin{align}
 V' &= 2 \alpha x_1 x'_1 + 4 \beta x_2^3 x'_2 \\
 &=2 \alpha x_1(-x_1 -x_2^3) + 4 \beta x^3_2(x_1-x_2)\\
 &=-2 \alpha x_1^2 -2 \alpha x_1 x^3_2 + 4 \beta x_1 x^3_2 - 4 \beta x^4_2 \\
 &=-2 \alpha x^2_1 + x_1 x^3_2(4 \beta -2 \alpha) -4 \beta x^4_2
\end{align}

Now, what if we let $4 \beta - 2 \alpha = 0 \rightarrow 4 \beta = 2 \alpha$ to get rid of the $x_1 x^3_2$ term, we have:

$$V' = -2 \alpha x^2_1 - 4 \beta x^4_2 = -2 \alpha x^2_1 - 2 \alpha x^4_2 = -2 \alpha (x^2_1 + x^4_2)$$

Clearly this is negative $\forall (x_1,x_2)$, so we have (since $4 \beta = 2 \alpha \rightarrow \beta = \dfrac{\alpha}{2}$):

$$V(x_1, x_2) = \alpha x^2_1 + \beta x^4_2 = \alpha x^2_1 + \dfrac{\alpha}{2} x^4_2$$

Lets verify this:

\begin{align}
V' &= 2 \alpha x_1 x'_1 + 2 \alpha x^3_2 x'_2\\ 
&= 2 \alpha x_1(-x_1-x^3_2)+ 2 \alpha x^3_2(x_1-x_2) \\
&= -2 \alpha x^2_1 -2 \alpha x_1 x^3_2 + 2 \alpha x_1 x^3_2 - 2 \alpha x^4_2\\
&= -2 \alpha (x^2_1 + x^4_2)
\end{align}

That checks out and meets all the criteria for a Liapunov function.

Note: do you now see where you made a slight error with the derivative?

This is telling us there are no closed orbits and we can see this in a phase portrait plot as follows (we could have also found the Jacobian and critical points to determine this).

[image]

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Please see answer above.

Comment: Nice work! (+1)

Comment: No, I'm not done. I'm done for the week, but back again on Monday. Good news is I don't have to be admitted, inpatient, but will need to spend the next week or two (weekdays) at L'Hospital ;-)